# Элементы формы WinAPI

Tags: winapi, форма

Здравствуйте! Подскажите,пожалуйста, как это добавить на форму?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стиль `BS_GROUPBOX`.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov т.е. создать рамки с подписью "Сообщения" и "Информация",а внутри них разместить list box?